# How to stop email notification to update Wordpress core?

Tags: wordpress, email-notifications

I am getting email notifications asking to update WordPress core. I don't want to update my WordPress and don't want to receive any emails regarding it.

I have searched the internet but am not sure about any specific plugins or hooks.

Can anyone please guide me in regards to stopping these email prompts to update WordPress?

Thank you.

Comment: It's better to get notified and update the Wordpress to make use of new updated features and other performance fixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the Automatic updates in functions.php:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

*If you want just the email to be turned off, use the below:*

You can set the status to false for `auto_core_update_send_email`. Below code goes in functions.php

```
// Disable update emails
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: The hook auto_core_update_send_email is about sending an email FOLLOWING an automatic background core update. It is not a hook about update prompt emails that the question is about.